# Weierstrass definition of the Gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, gamma-function, infinite-product

I want to cite Weierstrass's paper on his definition of the Gamma Function. So far I couldn't find any: I went to Wikipedia's page for the Gamma Function and it didn't cite his paper, I went to the Wikipedia page for the Weierstrass Factorization theorem and it didn't cite his paper. So do you know where to find the paper that has his definition?

Comment: the paper should be here:  https://www.degruyter.com/journal/key/crll/1856/51/html?lang=en

Comment: and for possibly other classical complex analysis stuff references, Remmert two volumes in the domain have all the historical stuff with all the citations; the above comes from Remmert II (Classical Topics in Complex Function Theory) page 34 and the reference therein, which an easy check of the link above (sadly not free, needs some academic affiliation to access) shows that is correct

Comment: Weierstrass published relatively little. He gave several courses of lectures and some of his students took lecture notes and published some of those.

Comment: @Conrad so which link is the one I need to cite?

Comment: Weierstrass, Karl. "Über die Theorie der analytischen Facultäten." , vol. 1856, no. 51, 1856, pp. 1-60. https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.1856.51.1      If you go at the link, you will see a "cite this" button - I c/p from there above

Comment: @Conrad thank you so much!

Comment: @Conrad Make this an answer so you could get +25 :)